# Loop through several arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management?

Tags: arcpy

I have several make query and feature class to feature class arcpy tools that create the necessary feature classes from my SQL queries. Is there a way to incorporate this into a for loop?

```
arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(input_database=db,
                                out_layer_name ='test1lyr',
                                query = test1,
                                oid_fields = "test1id")

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('test1lyr', scratchGDB, 'test1')

arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(input_database=db,
                                out_layer_name ='test2lyr',
                                query = test2,
                                oid_fields = "test2id")

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('test2lyr', scratchGDB, 'test2')

arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(input_database=db,
                                out_layer_name ='test3lyr',
                                query = test3,
                                oid_fields = "test3id")

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('test3lyr', scratchGDB, 'test3')

arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(input_database=db,
                                out_layer_name ='test4lyr',
                                query = test4,
                                oid_fields = "test4id")

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('test4lyr', scratchGDB, 'test4')

arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(input_database=db,
                                out_layer_name ='test5lyr',
                                query = test5,
                                oid_fields = "test5id")

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('test5lyr', scratchGDB, 'test5')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

```
# However these are defined
queries = [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5]

for i,query in enumerate(queries, 1):
    layer = arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management(input_database=db,
                                            out_layer_name='test{}lyr'.format(i),
                                            query=query,
                                            oid_fields="test{}id".format(i))[0]

    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(layer, scratchGDB, 'test{}'.format(i))
```

`enumerate()` removes the need for a counter and `.format()` with `i` ensures that no data will be overwritten.

Comment: That worked. One more question - I've updated my sql queries to have a unique name.  From queries = [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5] to queries = [test90, test180, g_test30HIH, g_test90HIH, g_test180HIH]... Using the example above, how would I use .format to name my results test90ly rather than test1lyr, and g_test180HIHlry rather than test5lyr Etc.? Thanks!

Comment: @arzola, one way would be to change `queries` to a dictionary like `{'name of layer1' : 'the query to use for 1', 'name of layer2' : 'query 2'}` `out_layer_name=key` and `query=value`